# How to convert BI/reporting Request into SQL statements

Tags: java, sql, analytics, business-intelligence

I am trying to create a data analytics service that can be used by REST client. REST request needs to send a ANSI SQL queries. Challenge is client/UI team wants to create their own Tableau like drag and drop style user interface where User can see parts of their data and build reports with it. So to bridge the gap between such UI and Analytics service, someone needs to convert form data into SQL Statements (we ruled out json based descriptive rest payload as it doesn't scale for full fledge sql). Datasource Metadata (tables, columns, datatypes etc) is available via REST api to UI so UI can send them back with their API request to some another service which can do SQL transformation. This service can also access API that describe relationships between tables/datasources (join, start-schema etc). so such service has enough information on what kind of SQL queries to form based on user selection. It doesn't need to optimize the query as it will be done by backend data analytics service. Is this seems like a good approach? I wonder UI visualization tool connecting via JDBC to datasources taking same approach. Any other suggestions are welcome.
Also, I can see such middleware service can be a generic framework for development of analytics or cubing visualization tool.

Comment: expose database strucure ... bad idea. Seems XY problem, what is MAIN reason to make that solution?

Comment: You create presentation layer on top of DB structure and then you expose that not underlaying physical structure. BI tools like OBIEE does the same.

Comment: this sounds like you want to develop ROLAP engine with web API - of course this is possible, but this might be not as easy when you dig into the details. Possibly it is good idea to use one of the existing solutions if you don't have really specific requirements.

Comment: We already have HOLAP query engine that accept SQL query. What we need is a service that can translate UI report into list of JDBC statements. Is that so hard problem to solve?